# Primefaces tabView header size incorrect in combination with accordionpanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I ran into a problem with a p:tabView displayed next to a p:accordionPanel. The tabView's header takes up the same vertical size as the whole of the accordionPanel.

Originally it was in a template client. I've reduced it to the following demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div>
            <div id="left" style="float: left">
                <p:accordionPanel>
                    <p:tab title="Accordion">
                        X<br/> 
                        Y<br/>
                        Z<br/>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
            </div>
            <div id="right" style="margin-left: 150px">
                <p:tabView>
                    <p:tab title="tabOne"> one </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0, GlassFish 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following style attribute for p:tabview

```
<p:tabView style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
      <p:tab title="tabOne"> one </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. Now back to the documentation to understand why.

Comment: PF documentation will not show you this. The css specs about using float might. Totally not PF related